# Issues with TimerTask

Tags: java, websphere, ilog, jrules

Hey all, Im working in IBM Websphere ILOG JRules 7.0 using RuleStudio (modified Eclipse) and am having an issue trying to implement a TimerTask.

I created a Techincal Rule based off a different rule that I know works and tried to add some code that would wait 5 seconds and then send a secondary message.  I tried this via the following code:

```
int interval = 5000; // 5 sec
java.util.Date timeToRun = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + interval);
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

timer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //  Message Sent Here
        }
    }, timeToRun);
```

However, this code does not compile.  The error it points out is on the open bracket right after `new java.util.TimerTask()` and the error messag is `at token "{"`.

Some interesting observations though:

-I tried doing `java.util.TimerTask test = new java.util.TimerTask();` and it throws an error at `new java.util.TimerTask();` saying `Could not find a public constructor (or argument mismatch) for java.util.TimerTask.`  Which I find odd since it's defintaly imported.

-I have Java version 1.6.0_17 installed on my comp, if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Strange. I have compiled this code w/o problem, if it of any help to you. Can you try to compile same code from console, via manual call to `javac`?

Comment: Not sure if itll let me since Techinal Rule files are .trl, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I meant I compiled snippet on plain Oracle JDK, no fancy .trl stuff :)

Comment: @Victor Yep its looking like it has to do with something ILOG Jrules specific, that code works fine in normal Java enviroments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed this was still open, turned out that the engine we were using has a customized java library on it that didnt include TimerTask... doh.  Went with a thread sleep command that the library actually had.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ILOG, but I'm guessing that this will probably work better:

```
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

class MyTask extends java.util.TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //  Message Sent Here
    }
}

timer.schedule(new MyTask(), timeToRun);
```

If that still doesn't work, take `MyTask` out of the method.

Comment: Didn't work, with the same `at token "{"` error on the open bracket after TimerTask... its like it has no clue what TimerTask is even when I directly import it.